# year calendar in extjs

Tags: extjs, calendar

I need a calendar made in ExtJS for the whole year. It should look like [this](http://www.calendarlabs.com/online-calendar.php)
Also I want to make some work with the calendar: hadle click event on a cell (date) and change the background color of the cell on click.

I have found  Ext.DatePicker in docs but I can't find any info on how to make it show month and year I need. Also I can't find any way to change the color of cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new component with 12 Ext.DatePicker and in each Ext.DatePicker show one diferent month.

Comment: Hi did you build it? Im having same requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me doing this I think I'd start by looking at the Ext.js source file \src\widgets\DatePicker.js, in particular the onRender method, and modify the code to acheive a display like the one you demonstrated.

I'm not aware of any Ext components which will give you the presentation you're looking for and so it'd be a question of building it yourself.

Maybe that helps a little?